# Segmentation Fault on Simple C++ Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is a follow up to my previous question. I have some code which should be running fine, and it does for the most part. When I run it, most of the `main` method runs but I get a segmentation fault when the getter methods are executed. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{

protected:
  string m_FirstName, m_LastName, m_email;

public:
  Person(){}
  Person(const string& firstName, const string& lastName) :
    m_FirstName(firstName), m_LastName(lastName)
       {}

        string get_name() const
        {
                return m_FirstName;
        }
        string get_surname() const
        {
                return m_LastName;
        }



        bool has_email_p()
        {

        }
};

class Person_with_telephone: public Person
{

protected:
  string m_telephone;

public:
  Person_with_telephone(){}
  Person_with_telephone(const string& telephone) : m_telephone(telephone)
  {}

   bool has_telephone_p()
        {
                if (m_telephone == "")
                {
                  cout  << "You have no phone number registered" << endl;
          return false;
                }

                else
                {
                  cout  << "Your number is: " << m_telephone << endl;
          return true;
                }
        }

       string get_telephone() const
        {
                 return m_telephone;
        }

  string set_telephone()
  {

  }

  string get_telephone()
  {

  }


};

int main()
{
  string f, l, ph;

        cout << "Enter fist name: ";
        cin >> f;
        cout << "Enter Last name: ";
        cin >> l;
    cout << "Enter telephone number: ";
    cin >> ph;
        Person p(f, l);
    Person_with_telephone pwt(ph);
        cout << "Your name is: " << p.get_name() << " " << p.get_surname() << endl;
    cout << "Has telephone? " << endl << " Your number is: " << pwt.get_telephone() << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

When I compile it compiles fine and when I run I get asked for the three inputs of Name, Surname and Telephone, but when I input the last value I get this:[Odd segfault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7EKl.png)

Comment: Please read [compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2627ecb212a280)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question, "How do I troubleshoot a segmentation fault?" If so, why include so much code?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in `Person_with_telephone::get_telephone()`.  This will cause a segfault.

If you [compile with proper warnings turned on](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589bacf498769e96) Then you should at least get

```
main.cpp:32:9: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
        }
        ^
main.cpp:69:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
main.cpp:74:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  }
  ^
3 warnings generated.
```

Which would let you know that you need return statements in those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bool has_email_p()`, `string get_telephone()` and `string set_telephone()` functions don't do or, more importantly, `return` anything.